# UI looks cropped in initial load for ios using xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, listview, user-interface, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

```
<ListView>
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ContentView Padding="6,2,6,2">
                                <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="5" Margin="10,5" HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  </Frame><Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                     <Label Grid.Row="0"  Text="Item1" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1"  Text="Item2" />
 <Label Grid.Row="2"  Text="Item3" />
</Grid>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

While with the initial load of the page UI looks like 3rd label is cropped and if I revisits the page the 3rd label showing correctly.how to show the UI perfectly with the initial load itself.issue is only occuring in ios.

Comment: Hi, I have updated an answer, you can have a look at it when have time. Because not knowing the code about "revisits the page", you also can share that part of code.

Answer (score 0):

From shared code, I have tested in local site on iOS. **However**, there is no problem in iOS device.

**In addition**, there is problems about this **Xaml** code. The **Frame** layout not contains the **Grid** , the running effect as follows:

[image]

If I put it inside will show as follows:

[image]

I also tested in Android device, however it cropped the third lable. If want to make it shows fully, we can add `RowHeight` for `ListView`, as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" RowHeight="125">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ContentView Padding="6,2,6,2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="White"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            HasShadow="False"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                    Text="Item1" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                    Text="Item2" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="2"
                                    Text="Item3" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                           
                           
                </ContentView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The effect:

[image]